# Can transactions be forced to occur sequentially in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, innodb

Let's say that I have two servers that simultaneously initiate a transaction on a MySQL 5.5 database using InnoDB. Both transactions do the same thing: Read a single row, then update the row based on its contents. I want to ensure that the two transactions run one after the other. That is, **the second transaction should not be allowed to read the row until the first transaction is complete.** Ideally, this would mean that the `SELECT` statement in the second transaction would wait until the first transaction has been committed, then return the updated values.

Is this possible? If not, is there a database that would be better suited to this task than MySQL?

If so, a related question: Suppose the first server crashed mid-transaction, so no `COMMIT` message was ever received. How would I go about setting a timeout after which the transaction would automatically roll back, so that the second transaction wouldn't be delayed forever? (**Update**: I've spun this off as a [separate question](https://serverfault.com/questions/241823/setting-a-time-limit-for-a-transaction-in-mysql-innodb).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` might satisfy your needs.  [See here.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-locking-reads.html)

Comment: Thanks, that got me on the right track, though I'd still like to see a more complete answer.

Answer (score 5):

OK, I took Shane's suggestion and turned it into a test case. I've got a table called `nsync` with a row with id `1` and value `foo`. Then I run this transaction:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT * FROM nsync WHERE id = '1' FOR UPDATE;
SELECT SLEEP(10);
UPDATE nsync SET stringy = 'bar' WHERE id = '1';
COMMIT;
```

and during the sleep interval I run

```
SELECT * FROM nsync WHERE id = '1' FOR UPDATE;
```

It works! The `SELECT` waits until the first transaction has completed, and returns the updated value `bar`.

Note that it's important that **both** `SELECT` statements use `FOR UPDATE`; if the first `SELECT` didn't use it, then the row wouldn't be locked; and if the second `SELECT` didn't use it, it wouldn't care about the lock.