# Setting a time limit for a transaction in MySQL/InnoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb

This sprang from [this related question](https://serverfault.com/questions/241765/), where I wanted to know how to force two transactions to occur sequentially in a trivial case (where both are operating on only a single row). I got an answer—use `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` as the first line of both transactions—but this leads to a problem: **If the first transaction is never committed or rolled back, then the second transaction will be blocked indefinitely.** The `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` variable sets the number of seconds after which the client trying to make the second transaction would be told "Sorry, try again"... but as far as I can tell, they'd be trying again until the next server reboot. So:

1. Surely there must be a way to force a `ROLLBACK` if a transaction is taking forever? Must I resort to using a daemon to kill such transactions, and if so, what would such a daemon look like?
2. If a connection is killed by `wait_timeout` or `interactive_timeout` mid-transaction, is the transaction rolled back? Is there a way to test this from the console?

**Clarification**: `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` sets the number of seconds that a transaction will wait for a lock to be released before giving up; what I want is a way of *forcing a lock to be released.*

**Update 1**: Here's a simple example that demonstrates why `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` is not sufficient to ensure that the second transaction is not blocked by the first:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT SLEEP(55);
COMMIT;
```

With the default setting of `innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50`, this transaction completes without errors after 55 seconds. And if you add an `UPDATE` before the `SLEEP` line, then initiate a second transaction from another client that tries to `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` the same row, it's the second transaction that times out, not the one that fell asleep.

What I'm looking for is a way to force an end to this transaction's restful slumber.

**Update 2**: In response to to hobodave's concerns about how realistic the example above is, here's an alternate scenario: A DBA connects to a live server and runs

```
START TRANSACTION
SELECT ... FOR UPDATE
```

where the second line locks up a row that the application frequently writes to. Then the DBA is interrupted and walks away, forgetting to end the transaction. The application grinds to a halt until the row is unlocked. I'd like to minimize the time that the application is stuck as a result of this mistake.

Comment: You just updated your question to completely conflict with your initial question. You state __in bold__ "If the first transaction is never committed or rolled back, then the second transaction will be blocked indefinitely." You disprove this with your latest update: " it's the second transaction that times out, not the one that fell asleep." -- seriously?!

Comment: I suppose my phrasing could have been clearer. By "blocked indefinitely," I meant that the second transaction would time out with an error message that says "try restarting transaction"; but doing so would be fruitless, because it would just time out again. So the second transaction is blocked—it will never complete, because it will keep timing out.

Comment: @Trevor: Your phrasing was perfectly clear. You've simply updated your question to ask a completely different thing, which is extremely bad form.

Comment: The question has always been the same: It's a **problem** that the second transaction is blocked indefinitely when the first transaction is never committed or rolled back. I want to force a `ROLLBACK` on the first transaction if it takes more than `n` seconds to complete. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: @Trevor: In what circumstance is the first transaction "never committed or rolled back"?

Comment: @hobodave Suppose that I send `BEGIN TRANSACTION; SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` from my client, then do nothing. Or, to simulate this, if I send `SELECT SLEEP(1000)` mid-transaction. Then the row ends up locked for an unacceptably long length of time. I want to force a `ROLLBACK` on that transaction, and perhaps disconnect the client.

Comment: @TrevorBurnham I am also wonder why `MYSQL` does't have a configuration to prevent this scenario. Because it is not acceptable of server hang due to clients irresponsibility. I didn't find any difficulty to understand your question also it is so relevant.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

More than half this thread seems to be about how to ask questions on ServerFault. I think the question makes sense and is pretty simple: How do you automatically roll back a stalled transaction?

One solution, if you're willing to kill the whole connection, is to set wait_timeout/interactive_timeout. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936699/mysql-rollback-on-transaction-with-lost-disconnected-connection.

Answer (score 3):

Since your question is asked here on ServerFault it is logical to assume that you are seeking a MySQL solution to a MySQL problem, particularly in the realm of knowledge that a system administrator and/or a DBA would have expertise in. As such, the following section addresses your questions:

> If the first transaction is never committed or rolled back, then the second transaction will be blocked indefinitely

No, it won't. I think you're not understanding [`innodb_lock_wait_timeout`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_lock_wait_timeout). It does exactly what you need.

It will return with an error as stated in the manual:

```
ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

- By definition, this is not *indefinite*. If your application is reconnecting and blocking repeatedly then *your application* is "blocking indefinitely", not the transaction. The second transaction blocks very definitely for `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` seconds.

By default, the transaction will not be rolled back. It is the responsibility of your application code to decide how to handle this error, whether that's trying again, or rolling back.

If you want automatic rollback, that is also explained in the manual:

> The current transaction is not rolled back. (To have the entire transaction roll back, start the server with the [`--innodb_rollback_on_timeout`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_rollback_on_timeout) option.

---

#### RE: Your numerous updates and comments

First, you have stated in your comments that you "meant" to say that you want a way to timeout the *first* transaction that is blocking indefinitely. This is not apparent from your original question and conflicts with "If the first transaction is never committed or rolled back, then the second transaction will be blocked indefinitely".

Nonetheless, I can answer that question as well. The MySQL protocol does not have a "query timeout". This means that you cannot timeout the first blocked transaction. You must wait until it is finished, or kill the session. When the session is killed the server will automatically roll the transaction back.

The only other alternative would be to use or write a mysql library which utilizes non-blocking I/O which would permit your *application* to kill the thread/fork making the query after N seconds. The implementation and usage of such a library are beyond the scope of ServerFault. This is an appropriate question for [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

Secondly, you've stated the following in your comments:

> I was actually more concerned in my question with a scenario in which the client app hangs (say, gets caught in an infinite loop) during the course of a transaction than with one in which the transaction takes a long time on MySQL's end.

This was not at all apparent in your original question, and still is not. This could only be discerned after you shared this rather important tidbit in the comment.

If this is actually the problem you are trying to solve, then I'm afraid you have asked it on the wrong forum. You have described an application level programming problem which requires a programming solution, one which MySQL cannot provide, and is outside of the scope of this community. Your latest answer answers the question "How do I prevent a Ruby program from infinitely looping?". That question is off-topic for this community and should be asked on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Sorry, but while is true when the transaction is waiting for a lock (as the name and documentation of `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` suggest), it isn't so in the situation I posed: where the client hangs or crashes before it gets the change to do a `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`.

Comment: @Trevor: You are simply wrong. This is trivial to test on your end. I just tested it on my end. Please take back your downvote.

Comment: @hobo, just because your right doesn't mean he has to like it.

Comment: Chris, could you explain how he's right? How will the second transaction occur if no `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` message is sent to resolve the first transaction? Hobodave, perhaps it would be helpful if you presented your test code.

Comment: @Trevor: You're not making a bit of sense. You want to serialize transactions, right? Yes, you said so in your other question and repeat that here in this question. If the first transaction has not completed, how on earth would you expect the second transaction to complete? You have explicitly told it to wait for the lock to be released on that row. Therefore, it must wait. What do you not understand about this?

Comment: Ah, that's where our miscommunication comes from. I didn't mean to imply that the second transaction is *dependent* on the first transaction, only that I don't want them to occur simultaneously (that is, to both read the same data and then perform an update). An example would be if both transactions were to increment a value (and yes, I know there are better ways of doing this). If the first transaction hanged, I wouldn't want that to prevent the second one from occurring.

Comment: "If a connection dies mid transaction, the transaction is implicitly rolled back on the server." OK, so the entire transaction is rolled back after `wait_timeout` seconds have elapsed, or by some other means? (The default value of `wait_timeout` is 8 hours.) Could you give me documentation or, better yet, a way of testing this, so I don't have to take it on faith? This was, in fact, part of my original question (#2 in the list).

Comment: @Trevor: I have answered every question of yours 4x over. The answers to your latest round of questions are also answered by my answer, or could be easily answered by a minimal amount of effort on your part. I feel you've abused my goodwill, and I've lost interest in helping you further. Please put some effort into it yourself.

Comment: I realize that you're upset about being downvoted. You're an expert. But the fact is, you misinterpreted the question. I'll be happy to retract the downvote if you answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

We want to kill transactions that are idle and are blocking the table(s) that I want to use.

It's easy enough to kill the thread that has the lock, in the example from the original question the lock was on a single table where no changes had been made so it would be fast **but be careful** if the killed transaction had been running for hours and had loads of data to rollback it will take some time to complete the rollback before you can use it.

`interactive_timeout` -- will kill sleeping connections including the ones with an open transaction; it will also kill all connections with no transactions that are just sleeping.

`innodb_rollback_on_timeout` - does not do exactly what it sounds like (InnoDB will always rollback something on a time out if there is something to rollback -- this controls how much (see the documentation)

So let's be surgical and only kill the threads that need killing.

`show processlist` will not help you because it only shows you who's sleeping but not who has any kind of lock but this query will (this is MySQL 8 might work in older versions, I didn't try):

```
SELECT i.trx_mysql_thread_id thread, 
    i.trx_state, 
    trx_tables_in_use tbl_used, 
    trx_tables_locked tbl_locked, 
    p.USER, 
    p.DB, 
    p.COMMAND, 
    p.TIME, 
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, trx_started, now()) trx_time, 
    SUBSTRING(trx_query, 1, 40) 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST p 
  JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_TRX i 
    ON i.trx_mysql_thread_id = p.ID;
```

Notice - the columns TIME and trx_time -- the first is want you see in the processlist and the second is how long this transaction has been running.  Do not mistake them, if TIME is very low, 1 or 2 seconds, then this transaction appears to be doing something.  Also notice the trx_tables_in_use and trx_tables_locked tbl_locked columns if these are 0 this transaction will not block another query -- But is will block things like ALTER TABLE that require a "metadata lock".  Finally notice trx_state when you try this it will likely be "RUNNING" after you kill the transaction it could be "ROLLBACK" and you will still have to wait.

Now changing the above query to find only the thread_id(s) you'd like to kill:

```
SELECT i.trx_mysql_thread_id
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST p 
  JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_TRX i 
    ON i.trx_mysql_thread_id = p.ID
WHERE i.trx_state = 'RUNNING'    
    AND trx_tables_locked > 0
    AND p.COMMAND = 'Sleep'
    AND p.TIME > 60
```

Loop through the results and kill those threads.  You can add condition on the other tables too (only kill this user, only in that DB, ...) You can do this in a stored procedure called by the event manager or just have your code do this before it runs (your user may need enhanced permission - I believe you can kill your own user).

Good Luck,
Frank

Answer (score 1):

In a similar situation my team decided to use pt-kill (https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-kill.html). It can report on or kill queries that (among other things) are running for too long. It's then possible to run it in a cron every X minutes.

Problem was that a query that had an unexpectedly long (e.g. indefinite) execution time locked a backup procedure that tried to flush tables with read lock, which in turn locked out all other queries on "waiting for tables to flush" which then never timed out because they're not waiting for a lock, which resulted with no errors in the application, which ultimately resulted with no alerts to administrators and application halting.

The fix was obviously to fix the initial query, but in order to avoid the situation accidentally happening in the future, it would be great if it was possible to auto-kill (or report on) transactions/queries that last longer than specific time,  which author of the question seems to be asking. This is doable with pt-kill.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution will be to have a stored procedure to kill the queries that take more time than your required `timeout` time and use `innodb_rollback_on_timeout` option along with it.

Answer (score -2):

After Googling around for a while, it looks like there's no *direct* way to set a per-transaction time limit. Here's the best solution I was able to find:

The command

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```

gives you a table with all of the commands currently being run and the time (in seconds) since they started. When a client has stopped giving commands, then they're described as giving a `Sleep` command, with the `Time` column being the number of seconds since their last command completed. So you could manually go in and `KILL` everything that has a `Time` value over, say, 5 seconds if you're confident that no query should take more than 5 seconds on your database. For instance, if the process with id 3 has a value of 12 in its `Time` column, you could do

```
KILL 3;
```

The documentation for the [KILL syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/kill.html) suggests that a transaction being carried out by the thread with that id would be rolled back (though I haven't tested this, so be cautious).

But how to automate this and kill all overtime scripts every 5 seconds? The first comment on [that same page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/kill.html) gives us a hint, but the code is in PHP; it seems that we can't do a `SELECT` on `SHOW PROCESSLIST` from within the MySQL client.  Still, supposing we have a PHP daemon that we run every `$MAX_TIME` seconds, it might look something like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST");
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $process_id=$row["Id"];
    if ($row["Time"] > $MAX_TIME) {
      $sql="KILL $process_id";
      mysql_query($sql);
  }
}
```

Note that this would have the side effect of forcing *all* idle client connections to reconnect, not just those that are misbehaving.

If anyone has a better answer, I'd love to hear it.

**Edit:** There is at least one serious risk of using `KILL` in this way. Suppose that you use the script above to `KILL` every connection that's idle for 10 seconds. After a connection has been idle for 10 seconds, but before the `KILL` is issued, the user whose connection is being killed issues a `START TRANSACTION` command. They're then `KILL`ed. They send an `UPDATE` and then, thinking twice, issue a `ROLLBACK`. However, because the `KILL` rolled back their original transaction, the update went through immediately and can't be rolled back! See [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/242518/how-safe-is-the-kill-command-in-mysql/242538#242538) for a test case.

Comment: This comment is intended for future readers of this answer. Please don't do this, even if it is the accepted answer.

Comment: OK, rather than downvoting and leaving a snide comment, how about explaining why this would be a bad idea? The person who posted the original PHP script said that it kept their server from hanging; if there's a better way to achieve the same goal, show me.

Comment: The comment is not snide. It is a warning for all future readers to make no attempt at using  your "solution". Automatically killing long running transactions is a unilaterally terrible idea. It should _never be done_. That is the explanation. Killing sessions should be an exception, not a norm. The _root cause_ of your contrived problem is user error. You do not create technical solutions for DBAs who lock rows and then "walk away". You fire them.

Comment: @TrevorBurnham I have a similar question that the first thread holds the row lock crashes unexpectedly, how long will mysql need to detect that and rollback the transaction? Do you have experience for that? Is the still need `wait_timeout` as the accepted answer said ?

Answer (score -2):

As hobodave suggested in a comment, it is possible in some clients (though not, apparently, the `mysql` command-line utility) to set a time limit for a transaction. Here's a demonstration using ActiveRecord in Ruby:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'timeout'
require 'active_record'

Timeout::timeout(5) {
  Foo.transaction do
    Foo.create(:name => 'Bar')
    sleep 10
  end
}
```

In this example, **the transaction times out after 5 seconds and gets automatically rolled back**. (*Update in response to hobodave's comment:* If the database takes more than 5 seconds to respond, the transaction will be rolled back as soon as it does—not sooner.) If you wanted to ensure that all of your transactions time out after `n` seconds, you could build a wrapper around ActiveRecord. I'm guessing that this also applies to the most popular libraries in Java, .NET, Python, etc., but I haven't tested them yet. (If you have, please post a comment on this answer.)

Transactions in ActiveRecord also have the advantage of being safe if a `KILL` is issued, unlike transactions done from the command line. See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1561/mysql-client-believes-theyre-in-a-transaction-gets-killed-wreaks-havoc.

It does not appear to be possible to enforce a maximum transaction time on the server side, except through a script like the one I posted in my other answer.

Comment: You have overlooked that ActiveRecord uses synchronous (blocking) I/O. All that script is doing is interrupting the Ruby sleep command. If your `Foo.create` command blocked for 5 minutes the Timeout would not kill it. This is incompatible with the example provided in your question. A `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` could easily block for long periods of time, as could any other query.

Comment: It should be noted that nearly all mysql client libraries utilize blocking I/O, hence the suggestion in my answer that you would need to use or write your own that used non-blocking I/O. Here is a simple demonstration of the Timeout being useless: http://gist.github.com/856100

Comment: I was actually more concerned in my question with a scenario in which the client app hangs (say, gets caught in an infinite loop) during the course of a transaction than with one in which the transaction takes a long time on MySQL's end. But thanks, that's a good point. I've updated the question to note it.)

Comment: I cannot duplicate your claimed results. I updated the gist to utilize `ActiveRecord::Base#find_by_sql`: https://gist.github.com/856100 Again, this is because AR uses blocking I/O.

Comment: @hobodave Yes, that edit was erroneous and has been corrected. To be clear: The `timeout` method will roll back the transaction, but not until the MySQL database responds to a query. So the `timeout` method is suitable for preventing long transactions on the client side or long transactions that consist of several relatively short queries, but not for long transactions in which a single query is the culprit.

Comment: The terminology you use is misleading and doesn't accurately reflect what your script is doing. First, lets be clear that your question in its current state is asking how to time out long running mysql transactions. The Ruby code you provided is not doing that. You state "the timeout method will roll back the transaction". No, it won't. The timeout method is simply timing out a Ruby Thread. The fact that Thread just _happens_ to be in a MySQL transaction is tangential. ...

Comment: ... When the Ruby Thread is woken up and the timeout has been exceeded then what happens is _Ruby kills the Thread, which destroys the connection_. As a result of the connection closing the mysql server rolls back the transaction. This is an important distinction. Your script answers the question "How do I timeout an infinite loop in Ruby?". It does not answer the question you asked. Sure, you can try to use it as a timeout for infinite loops, but that is a problem not described in your question.

Comment: Basically your question is about how to "timeout transactions in MySQL", it has nothing to do with your application code. If you really meant to ask "How do I timeout long running application code that might happen to be in the middle of a MySQL transaction?", well, you answered _that_. But that has nothing to do with MySQL, and is better asked on StackOverflow.